# Flastlist moves to top every time after executing the 'onEndReached', if data is returned via 'Promis'

Tags: react-native

While using 'Flastlist' component, when user scrolls down and 'onEndReached' fires, the 'Flastlist'
loads data with out any issue, but it scroll back to the beginning of the list. This happens when extra rows are populated using 'Promis' while calling 'onEndReached'. If I returned row with out a 'Promis', it works fine.

System:
  OS: Windows 10
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3540  @ 2.16GHz
  Memory: 2.95 GB / 7.89 GB
Binaries:
  Yarn: 1.19.1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
  npm: 6.11.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
IDEs:
  Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203

I have uploaded the code here https://snack.expo.io/@sumeshcs1975/flatlist-onendreached
Scroll down and when it reaches the end of screen, Flastlist scroll back automatically to the top

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your code here, so that others can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, by quickly looking at your code, it may be due to the fact that you are re-rendering the whole FlatList.

When `makeRemoteRequest` is called, it does a `this.setState({ loading: true });` which triggers a re-rendering resulting in removing the FlatList from the screen and rendering the `ActivityIndicator`.

When you get the result, you set `loading: false` which in return removes the `ActivityIndicator` and renders the `FlatList`. So, because the whole FlatList is re-rendered, the default scroll position will be on the top. (Exactly like it's rendered for the first time)

Comment: Yes, this is what causing FlatList render and starts scroll from top. @Sumesh if you want to show a `ActivityIndicator` on FlatList scroll in bottom of list, can go for `ListFooterComponent` prop of FlatList

Comment: Thanks Andrei Olar & Droid Bug . I removed the activity indicator from there and  used the property 'ListFooterComponent' to show  'ActivityIndicator' and it worked fine. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Thanks, I faced the same issue and didn't notice!